# How to create in Recharts a custom vertical label for the YAxis that will scale to fit in case the label is too long?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I am building few composed charts using the Recharts library and some of the vertical labels on the `YAxis` are too long and are getting cut off.

[A picture of my labels that got cut off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUwrl.png)

I have tried to use a custom label with a `<Text>` element - it solves the cutting off issue by making the label smaller if I pass a `scaleToFit={true}` prop

```
const {PropTypes} = React;
const {ComposedChart, Line, Area, Bar, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, Text} = Recharts;
const data = [{name: 'Page A', uv: 590, pv: 800, amt: 1400},
              {name: 'Page B', uv: 868, pv: 967, amt: 1506},
              {name: 'Page C', uv: 1397, pv: 1098, amt: 989},
              {name: 'Page D', uv: 1480, pv: 1200, amt: 1228},
              {name: 'Page E', uv: 1520, pv: 1108, amt: 1100},
              {name: 'Page F', uv: 1400, pv: 680, amt: 1700}];

const CustomizedLabelB = ({ kapi, metric, viewBox }) => {
    return (
        <Text
            x={0}
            y={0}
            dx={-300}
            dy={40}
            textAnchor="start"
            width={180}
            transform="rotate(-90)"
            // If I uncomment the next line, then the rotation stops working.
            // scaleToFit={true}
        >            
            This_is_a_very_very_very_long_long_long_label_what_can_we_do_about_it?
        </Text>
    );
};

const SameDataComposedChart = React.createClass({
    render () {
    return (
        <ComposedChart width={600} height={400} data={data}
            margin={{top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20}}>
          <CartesianGrid stroke='#f5f5f5'/>
          <XAxis dataKey="name"  />
          <YAxis label={<CustomizedLabelB />} />
          <Tooltip/>
          <Legend/>
          <Bar dataKey='uv' barSize={20} fill='#413ea0'/>
          <Line type='monotone' dataKey='uv' stroke='#ff7300'/>
       </ComposedChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SameDataComposedChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

but the label doesn't rotate and remains horizontal.

[This is a link to my fiddle reproducing the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/DrBoomerang/msd2xf8h/19/)

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution - you should use the 'angle' prop in the  element instead of the 'transform="rotate(x)".